# MongoDB C# Driver 'Cursor not found'

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have quite an intensive operation that has a `MongoCursor` run in a loop for a few hours (on a vb.net app running via the c# driver. I'm not too sure what causes it but I run into an exception after a while

```
Cursor not found
```

This could be because of a cursor timeout, perhaps? Is there a way I can stop it happening? If its a timeout issue how do I place a longer timeout?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can disable the cursor's timeout in the C# driver by calling:

```
cursor.SetFlags(QueryFlags.NoCursorTimeout);
```

Otherwise it will be closed after 10 minutes of inactivity.

[Reference](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-397)

Comment: If you don't exhaust the cursor to the last element, this will cause a memory leak in mongo.

Comment: You can also change the batch size (as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/24200795/420867 - it's a python question but the same should be possible with the C# mongo driver)

Answer (score 2):

Further clarifying JohnnyHK's answer, this is the syntax:

```
MongoCursor<BsonDocument> cursor = myCollection
                                   .Find(query)
                                   .SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending("TrackingNumber"))
                                   .SetFlags(QueryFlags.NoCursorTimeout);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using MongoDB.Driver version 2.4.4 and `IFindFluent` is not containing `SetFlags` method. using this instead:

```
cursor.Options.NoCursorTimeout = true;
```

Comment: What would happen if NoCursorTimeout is set to true and u have exhausted the cursor ? Would there be any memory leak or performance issues?