# MongoDB C# Driver 'Cursor not found' with Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to do a select at a Mongo database
I'm using this DLL

`MongoDB.Bson,MongoDB.Driver,MongoDB.Driver.Linq`

My table have more than 55k rows

After some time occurs this error

> Cursor Not Found

Here is my code

```
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);        
var server = client.GetServer();        
var database = server.GetDatabase("Database");
var collection = database.GetCollection<DesktopSessions>("desktop_sessions");
var query = (from e in collection.AsQueryable<DesktopSessions>()
            where e.created_at > new DateTime(2012, 7, 1)
            select e);
foreach (var item in query)
{
    string id = item._id.ToString();
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you put the new DateTime() into a variable first, then run the query does it work better?

Comment: how much time is some time? you could maybe reach a timeout on the cursor

Comment: @I3arnon The default timeout for a cursor is 10 minutes.  Unless the `noTimeout` flag is set.

Comment: How can I change the timeout? the process takes more than 10 minutes

Comment: @JoséArthurOrtizAntunes according to http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/, it is closed after 10 minutes of inactivity.  Otherwise, there should be a setting somewhere in the driver for turning off cursor timeout, just remember that means the server won't clean up cursors, so you have to.

Comment: Please note that is **10 minutes of inactivity** so if the cursor is iterating it is not timing out. It might help to add more specific information on what is happening in the loop and the actual timings, rows iterated etc.

Comment: You can [disable the cursor timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14056796/1259510), but that's really a last resort.

Comment: How can I set the timeout? 'cursor.setflag()' does not exist in linq

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB C# Driver 'Cursor not found'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053803/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-cursor-not-found)

Answer (score 2):

I changed my code to this

```
 var collection = database.GetCollection<DesktopSessions>("desktop_sessions");
 var queryM = Query.GTE("created_at", new BsonDateTime(new DateTime(2012,7,1)));
 var cursor = collection.Find(queryM);
 cursor.SetFlags(QueryFlags.NoCursorTimeout);
```

It Works!!

Comment: If you fail to exhaust the cursor, the server will never clean it up, and it will be a resource leak, where the resources won't be cleaned up until the mongod process is restarted.  It is important to exhaust the cursor or find a way to do it without `NoCursorTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to set the timeout for whole database which is what I am doing.
You can do it in configuration, command line, mongo shell, or even C#.

see here:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8188

This is the solution I am using currently in my init class

```
var db = this.MongoClient.GetDatabase("admin");
var cmd = new BsonDocumentCommand<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument {
  { "setParameter", 1 },
  { "cursorTimeoutMillis", 3600000 } 
});
db.RunCommand(cmd);
```

More information could be find here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/parameters/#param.cursorTimeoutMillis