# CursorNotFound error in Pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to run the following in Python (with pymongo), however I always get the error message:

```
CursorNotFound: Cursor not found, cursor id: 16172789264
```

The code that I have (I tried to set "batch_size", but the error message continued):

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = client['tese']
carteiras_cvm = db['carteiras_cvm']

pipeline_acoes =[{"$unwind":"$posicao"},
           {"$match" : {"posicao.detalhes.Tipo de Aplicação:" : { "$in" : ['Ações','Brazilian Depository Receipt - BDR',
           'Ações e outros TVM cedidos em empréstimo','AÇÕES RECEBIDAS EM BONIFICAÇÃO']}}},
           {"$project":{"cnpj_fundo":"$cnpj_fundo", "data_carteira":"$data_carteira", "tipo_aplicacao":"$posicao.detalhes.Tipo de Aplicação:","cod_ativo":"$posicao.detalhes.Cod Ativo:","cod_isin":"$posicao.detalhes.Cod ISIN:","cod_isin":"$posicao.detalhes.Cod ISIN:","descricao":"$posicao.detalhes.Descrição:","posicao_final":"$posicao.posicao_final","perc_carteira":"$posicao.perc_carteira","pl_fundo":"$pl_posicao"}}]


def aggregate(db, pipeline):
    return [doc for doc in carteiras_cvm.aggregate(pipeline).batch_size(5)]

resultados_acoes = aggregate(carteiras_cvm, pipeline_acoes)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your cursor is timeing out, see the following answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24200795/4273834

Answer (score 1):

Try add "no_cursor_timeout=True" in your cursor.

```
[doc for doc in carteiras_cvm.aggregate(pipeline,no_cursor_timeout=True).batch_size(5)]
```

Do tell me if this worked for you.

if the above code doesn't work try this link..

[Is it possible to create an aggregation in Pymongo with no timeout for the cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40248820/is-it-possible-to-create-an-aggregation-in-pymongo-with-no-timeout-for-the-curso)

Comment: I tried this, but in the end I formatted my laptop and then the error message disappeared

Answer (score 1):

`no_cursor_timeout` is not valid for method `aggregate()` in pymongo.
You can use `maxTimeMS` instead.

> `maxTimeMS` (int): The maximum amount of time to allow the operation
>               to run in milliseconds.