# Is it possible to create an aggregation in Pymongo with no timeout for the cursor?

Tags: python, find, aggregate, pymongo

The aggregation looks like:

```
res = Things.objects._collection.aggregate(pipeline,
            allowDiskUse=True,
            batchSize=101,
            noCursorTimeout=True
        )
```

and fails with

> OperationFailure: unrecognized field 'noCursorTimeout'

It appears from the Pymongo documentation that no_cursor_timeout can be used with find(), however I have been unsuccessful locating a comparable **kwargs for aggregate().

I do not want to use setParameter or maxTimeMS.

UPDATE:

From MongoDB's Jira Site: [SERVER-15042](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15042)

The NoCursorTimeout bit in the OP_QUERY header prevents the server from closing a cursor that's idle for more than 10 minutes. Clients can set this bit if they may spend more than 10 minutes processing a batch of results.

The "aggregate" and "parallelCollectionScan" commands should allow the client to turn off cursor timeouts, too.

The response to this ticket was:

> We intentionally do not support noCursorTimeout. The rationale for
>   needing this will go away when we implement cursor keepalive. That
>   work will be tracked in SERVER-6036.

Looking at [SERVER-6036](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6036):

- Updated: Sep 14 2016 03:53:05 PM GMT+0000
- Status: OPEN
- Resolution: Unresolved
- Fix Version/s: planned but not scheduled

If I have read the documents correctly, a cursor no timeout option does not exist yet for aggregate().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're correct, cursor timeout can't be disabled on individual aggregation cursors. But we've provided a global config setting, `cursorTimeoutMillis`, that you can increase to a large number:

```
mongod --setParameter cursorTimeoutMillis=600000  # 10 minutes
```

See [SERVER-8188](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8188) for MongoDB version info, and how to set this parameter at runtime.